# Предлагаю сделать просмотр сайта удобнее

Tags: предложение, изображения

Вот задал я вопрос да? В нём есть изображение. Чтобы сделать удобнее для тех кто читает мой вопрос, мне надо делать такие фокусы.

[image]
[<kbd>Открыть изображение</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icZH0.png)

Вот как это выглядит изнутри

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icZH0.png
![][1]
[<kbd>Открыть изображение</kbd>][1]
```

---

Предлагаю немного автоматизировать этот момент. Плюс добавить некоторые функции как например - "оставить комментарии на изображении" или же "копировать текст из изображении" (допустим в картинке небольшой код и чтобы отдельно не выложить его можно оставить его в комментариях и чтобы при нажатии скопировалась).

---

*Как вам моя идея? Был бы рад услышать ваши мнения.*

---

## Уточнение

Пример для "копировать текст из изображении". Это может выглядеть так же как и просмотр фотографий в соц. сетях. Наводишь мышку на указанную область и показывает текст который будет скопировано при нажатии, а эта область выбрать будет пользователь конечно же, не ИИ.

[image]

Comment: А смысл, если сейчас клик по изображению делает то же самое?

Comment: Скопировать текст - непонятно, что там за текст и где. Не уверен, что хочу копировать текст наугад.

Comment: @Qwertiy для телефонов не удобно для начала, потом комментарии же можно только под картинкой. А если мне нужно одной картинкой объяснить ситуацию?

Comment: @Qwertiy я не говорю что функционал отсутствует просто чтобы было кратко, удобно и без лишних тегов.

Comment: Я только за то, чтобы клик по изображению открывал его в отдельной вкладке. Лично мне этого очень не хватает.

Comment: @nomnoms12 По умолчанию же так. Здесь автор просто ссылку убрал.

Comment: @defaultlocale У меня клик по изображению на основном сайте открывает его в той же вкладке. Поэтому приходится делать `ПКМ -> Открыть ссылку в новой вкладке`. Это раздражает меня. Пока писал этот комментарий, пришла идея написать `UserScript` для этого.

Comment: @nomnoms12, можно средней кнопкой кликать - тогда сразу в новой вкладке открыват :)

Comment: @Grundy И правда! Спасибо большое :D